# Sometimes when using Sheepit I get the error "Internal Error, no token for adding a project"

Tags: sheepit, error

I don't know what causes this, but sometimes I get "Internal error, no token for adding a project" after I've waited the hour for my file to upload. Admittedly, I sometimes wait 8 hours or more because I upload in the morning and hadn't in the past had access to my PC while at school. [image]

Answer (score 0):

**This is my therory:** I think the maximum number of projects in the waiting list is reached, that's why you can't add yours. Unchecking "Renderable by all members" before clicking submit helps. Your projects is then private but still uploaded and you could try checking "Renderable by all members" again if there are less projects rendering. You can't check it afterwards if there are too many projects, i tried that. But you still can add a Team even if its private or add members to your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a less than 30 minute timeout on the multi-part form.

Sheepit also has it's own forum, where your issue is discussed in greater detail (after Xylef happened to find your post here)

https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=425